# Content in prolog not allowed error importing project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to import an Eclipse project into Android Studio but this error shows up:

> Invalid XML file: C:*manifestlocation*\AndroidManifest.xml: Content is
>   not allowed in prolog.

Now this of course means that somehow my AndroidManifest file of the project I want to import is corrupt and has content before the first XML statement. But this is not the case. Here is my full manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.timkranen.flikrboard"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
            android:name="com.timkranen.extra.FetchAdressIntentService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

There is no content before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` line. The project is valid and works in Eclipse. But importing it into Android Studio is giving me this problems.

Any solutions? Is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: Are those spaces actually present before the `<?xml`? They would count as 'content'.

Comment: @greg-449 No, tripled checked for spaces. Let me edit my question so that's a bit more clearer.

Comment: Possibly a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start which is not understood by whatever is reading the XML.